# Scroll Jquery html css

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress

Preciso fazer um scroll mudar menu conforme ele desce idêntico a este site http://www.flatslife.com/ poderiam me ajudar aonde posso estar encontrando?

```
<div id="cssmenu" class="menu-agency-main-menu-container"><ul id="menu-agency-main-menu" class="menu nav nav-pills"><li id="menu-item-13123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/" class="nav-link" style="text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35) 0px 1px 0px;"><span style="border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);">INÍCIO</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13415" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-ativo a:first has-sub nav-item"><a class="nav-link" style="text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35) 0px 1px 0px;"><span style="border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);">A EMPRESA</span><span class="holder" style="border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu nav nav-pills" style="display: block;">
    <li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-ativo a:first nav-item dropdown"><a href="/a-empresa/#sobre" class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>Sobre a SHEVAR</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-ativo a:first nav-item dropdown"><a href="/a-empresa/#organograma" class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>Organograma</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-ativo a:first nav-item dropdown"><a href="/a-empresa/#equipe" class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>A Equipe</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-13388" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children has-sub nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/produtos-e-servicos/" class="nav-link" style="text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35) 0px 1px 0px;"><span style="border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);">PRODUTOS E SERVIÇOS</span><span class="holder" style="border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu nav nav-pills" style="display: block;">
    <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>SHEVAR PARTICIPAÇÕES</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu nav nav-pills" style="display: block;">
        <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item dropdown"><a href="/shevar-participacoes/#produtos-servicos" class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>Gestão de Ativos Imobiliário</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-10886" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item dropdown"><a href="/shevar-participacoes/#investimentos-participacoes" class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>Investimentos e Particiáções</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-10887" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item dropdown"><a href="/shevar-participacoes/#estruturacao-capital" class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>Estruturação de Capital</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-10888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>SHEVAR PARTNERS</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu nav nav-pills">
        <li id="menu-item-10889" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item dropdown"><a href="/shevar-partners/#credito-imobiliario" class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>Originação de Crédito Imobiliário</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-10890" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item dropdown"><a href="/shevar-partners/#operacao-credito" class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>Estruturação de Operações de Crédito</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-10891" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item dropdown"><a href="/shevar-partners/#cons-empresarial" class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>Consultoria Empresarial</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-10892" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item dropdown"><a href="/shevar-partners/#mercado" class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>Pesquisa de Mercado</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-10893" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item dropdown"><a href="/shevar-partners/#risco-ativos" class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>Avaliações e Análise de Risco de Ativos</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-10894" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item dropdown"><a href="/shevar-partners/#aquisicoes" class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>Fusões e Aquisições</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-13124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>SHEVAR SECURITIZADORA</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu nav nav-pills">
        <li id="menu-item-13125" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item dropdown"><a href="/shevar-securitizadora/#operacao-credito2" class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>Estruturações e Operações de Crédito</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-13126" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item dropdown"><a href="/shevar-securitizadora/#venda-ativos" class="nav-link dropdown-item"><span>Compra e Venda de Ativos</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-10895" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item"><a href="/parceiros" class="nav-link" style="text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35) 0px 1px 0px;"><span style="border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);">PARCEIROS</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13171" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/contato/" class="nav-link" style="text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35) 0px 1px 0px;"><span style="border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);">Contato</span></a></li>
</ul></div>
```

quero que fique ativo apenas 1 menu porém fica todos os sub-menu ativo sendo que era pra ficar somente 1

Comment: Posta o que vc já tem de código fica mais fácil pra te dar uma resposta direito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo bem básico feito só com CSS não tem jQuery, nem JS, nem nenhum framework. *Aqui é apenas uma ideia, vc pode pensar como adaptar dependendo do conteúdo que for usar, incluindo os `@media` necessários. Tentei fazer da forma que ficasse mais próximo do exemplo que vc citou. Outra forma seria com ancoras ai vc não fica preso em cada página ter que ter exatamente a altura da tela*

A ideia aqui é usar `labels` que ativam botões do tipo `radio` que ficam ocultos, quado o btn com o `id` correto é `:checked` ele "dispara" as regras CSS que fazem a animação acontecer.

De uma boa estudada no código que é bem fácil de entender. Como cada página tem `100vh` de altura eu uso um `margin-top`, que alinha a página que eu quero na tela. Tentei fazer o mais limpo possível, porém vc pode partir dai para customizar tudo etc.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1000;

}
nav label {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 8px 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: background-color 500ms ease;
}
nav label::after {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    content: attr(data-name);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 32px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease;
}
nav label:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.bloco {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 48px;
}
#p1 {
    background-color: #f00;
}
#p2 {
    background-color: #ff0;
}
#p3 {
    background-color: #f0f;
}
#p4 {
    background-color: #0f0;
}
#id1:checked ~ nav > label[for="id1"], 
#id2:checked ~ nav > label[for="id2"],
#id3:checked ~ nav > label[for="id3"],
#id4:checked ~ nav > label[for="id4"] {
    background-color: #fff;
}
#id1:checked ~ nav > label[for="id1"]::after, 
#id2:checked ~ nav > label[for="id2"]::after,
#id3:checked ~ nav > label[for="id3"]::after,
#id4:checked ~ nav > label[for="id4"]::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
.scroll {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
}
.sec {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: 0;
    transition: margin-top 1s ease;
}
#id1:checked ~ .scroll > .sec {
    margin-top: 0vh;
}
#id2:checked ~ .scroll > .sec {
    margin-top: -100vh;
}
#id3:checked ~ .scroll > .sec {
    margin-top: -200vh;
}
#id4:checked ~ .scroll > .sec {
    margin-top: -300vh;
}
[name="radio-grupo"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" checked name="radio-grupo" id="id1">
<input type="radio" name="radio-grupo" id="id2">
<input type="radio" name="radio-grupo" id="id3">
<input type="radio" name="radio-grupo" id="id4">
<nav>
    <label for="id1" data-name="nome 1"></label>
    <label for="id2" data-name="nome 2"></label>
    <label for="id3" data-name="nome 3"></label>
    <label for="id4" data-name="nome 4"></label>
</nav>
<main class="scroll">
    <section class="sec">
        <article class="bloco" id="p1">página 1</article>
        <article class="bloco" id="p2">página 2</article>
        <article class="bloco" id="p3">página 3</article>
        <article class="bloco" id="p4">página 4</article>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Entendi mais eu teria que usar scroll para mudar os menus conforme eu uso scroll

Comment: Nesse modelo a navegação só é permitida com o menu lateral. Como te falei é um exemplo simples só com CSS de onde vc pode partir para algo mais sofisiticado usando JavaScript. Acredito que com JS vc pode detectar o giro do mouse e trocar a tela. Além de trocar também qual bolinha está selecionada. Procure por Magic Scroll em jQuery ou algum plugin do tipo que pode te ajudar. Eu faço esse modelo pe acredito que podem ajudar de alguma forma, mas acredi que ninguém aqui vai te entregar um código 100% pronto, o site aqui é para tirar dúvidas e ajudar, não para fazer esse tipo de coisa.

Comment: este é meu menu ele fica ativo porem fica ativo todos os sub menus e não somente o que está na pagina postei no começo

Comment: @FilipeNickelSala se vc estiver usando Bootstrap use o ScrollSpy que vc resolve esse problema. Se não estiver usando Bootstrap procure algum plugin jQuery que faça o mesmo. Vai te ajudar nisso. Ou então abra uma nova pergunta, coloque todo seu código CSS, JS e HTML e explica direito o que precisa que as vezes alguém pode te ajudar. Eu fiz essa resposta como base no que entendi da sua pergunta.